# Efficient way to take a product of vectors, and then apply an operator to the output matrix and then sum all of the matrices

Tags: r, performance, matrix

I have a dataset, `X`, with `n` rows and `d` columns.
I want to take the dot product with each row to the transpose of itself. In R code this would be `x %*% t(x)`, and this gives a `d` by `d` matrix.

I then truncate the values in the matrix using a function:
Where `tau` is a `d` by `d` matrix.

```r
trunc_operator = function(x, tau){

  x = ifelse(abs(x) > tau, tau*sign(x), x)
  return(x)

}
```

I do this for each row, and then sequentially add them together.

```r
acf_mat = matrix(0, ncol(data), ncol(data))
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  acf_mat = acf_mat + mat_prod_pairwise_trunc(data[i,], data[i,], tau = tau)
}
```

The reason I do this sequentially is so that I do not have to store many `d` by `d` matrices, but just one matrix at a time, and therefore less memory is used.

The `mat_prod_pairwise_trunc()` function is doing the dot product and then applying the `trunc_operator` function.

```r
mat_prod_pairwise_trunc = function(x,y, tau){
  trunc_operator((x %*% t(y))/2,tau)
}
```

However the for loop is slow, and I want to improve the speed.

**Ideas so far**

1. writing the whole *for* loop in C++ using [Rcpp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirk_Eddelbuettel)
2. Just writing the `trunc_operator()` function in C++
3. Use parallelisation, by maybe splitting the data into batches?

What is an efficient way of carrying this out?

---

**Reproducible Example**
Below is the code of the full example:

```r
# creating dataset
n = 200
d = 200

data = rt(n = n*d, df = 4.1)
data = matrix(data, nrow = n, ncol = d)

data_pairwise_fun = function(data){
  n = nrow(data)
  data_pairwise = matrix(nrow = (n*(n-1))/2, ncol = ncol(data))
  for(i in 1:(n-1)){
    for(j in 1:(n-i)){
      data_pairwise[((i-1) * n) - (i*(i-1)/2) + j, ] = data[i,] - data[i + j,]
    }
  }
  return(data_pairwise)
}

data = data_pairwise_fun(data)


# tau
t_tau_mat = function(df, delta, d, n){
  off = (df/(df-2))^2
  on = ((1/2)*((3*df^2)/(df - 2)*(df - 4))) + (3/2)*off

  V_mat = diag(on - off, nrow = d, ncol = d)
  V_mat = V_mat + off
  V_mat = sqrt(V_mat)
  V_mat * (sqrt(floor((n/2))/(2*log(d) + log(1/delta))))
}

tau = t_tau_mat(4.1,1/n,d,n)

# functions:
trunc_operator = function(x, tau){

  x = ifelse(abs(x) > tau, tau*sign(x), x)
  return(x)

}

mat_prod_pairwise_trunc = function(x,y, tau){
  trunc_operator((x %*% t(y))/2,tau)
}


# Main job:
acf_mat = matrix(0, ncol(data), ncol(data))
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  acf_mat = acf_mat + mat_prod_pairwise_trunc(data[i,], data[i,], tau = tau)
}
```

Comment: Can you add more information about the size of the matrix - how many rows, how many columns? maybe generate it in the example?

Comment: Yep, I will add an example section now. The matrices I am using this with have 19900 rows, and then I look at using matrices with the number columns going from 50 to 500.

Comment: Ideas 1 and 3 are good and would almost surely result in significant speed gains. Idea 2 I am doubtful of - do you have any reason to think the `trunc_operator()` is a major bottleneck? I would strongly suggest profiling the code to confirm where the slow parts are before targeting any individual part for optimization.

Comment: That said, `trunc_operator` could likely be improved in base R using `pmin()` and `pmax()`. I think `trunc_operator <- function(x, tau) pmin(tau, pmax(-tau, x))` will be more efficient.

Comment: (A quick benchmark on a length-1e6 vector shows my `trunc_operator` to be about 1.75 times faster than the `ifelse()` version. So some improvement.

Comment: It also seems unnecessary and inefficient to pass the same input twice to `mat_prod_pairwise_trunc`. It's already a quick function and is probably not at all a bottleneck, but 
changing it to `mat_prod_pairwise_trunc = function(x, tau){
  trunc_operator((x %*% t(x))/2,tau)
}`  makes it more than 2x faster.

Comment: Also, shouldn't your `abs(x) > tau` be `abs(x) < tau`? I assume you want to change elements that are lower than tolerance to the level of tolerance?

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius I want it how it is, as I want to truncate large values downwards.

Comment: And your tau is also a matrix?

Comment: @GregorThomas I also want to use `mat_prod_pairwise_trunc` to lagged rows. For example `x[i,]` with `x[i +l,]`. So requires different arguments. Thank you both of you btw, this is very useful.

Comment: Yes, I was just going to say that It needs to work with tau as a matrix. I have not checked if your solution with replacing ifelse still works when tau is not a matrix.

Comment: Your original solution also should not work with tau as a matrix. You would need to subset the i-th row when passing it to the function.

Comment: Why? I am using the same tau matrix for every row of the data. My original solution works, I give an example below where mine works and yours does not:
`x = matrix(c(1,2,3,4), 2, 2)`
`tau = matrix(c(2,2,1,2), 2, 2)`
Sorry, I should of made it clearer that tau is a matrix.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct, I missed that you do outer product before comparing with tau.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an [Rcpp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirk_Eddelbuettel) approach. It takes less than a second on the provided dataset:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction(
  "std::vector<std::vector<double>>
  funCpp(std::vector<std::vector<double>> &data,
         std::vector<std::vector<double>> &tau){
   int p = data.size(), n = data[0].size();
   std::vector<std::vector<double>> results(p, std::vector<double>(p));
   for(int i = 0; i < p; i++){
    for(int j = i; j < p; j++){
      double res = 0;
      double _tau = tau[i][j];
      for(int k = 0; k < n; k++){
        double ans = data[i][k] * data[j][k]/2;
        double sgn = (0 < ans) - (ans < 0);
        res += ans * sgn > _tau ? _tau * sgn : ans;
      }
      results[i][j] = res;
      results[j][i] = res;
    }
   }
  return results;
}")

funR <- function(data, tau){
  out <- funCpp(data.frame(data), data.frame(tau))
  simplify2array(out)
}

s <- funR(data, tau)
all.equal(s, original)
[1] TRUE
```

The final result, `s`, takes less than a second to compute. It is ~25 times faster than the original function. I was unable to use `microbenchmark` with the provided answers above as the first answer does not produce the same results as the original question.

Comment: Thanks for this, I noticed you put `tau[1:2]`, if i remove the `[1:2]` index will it still work if not all of the the off-diagonal elements of `tau` are the same?

Comment: @DylanDijk no it wont work. Are the taus different? if so, i can easily edit the code to make it work for a matrix tau. In your example, tau only has two values,

Comment: Yep you are right, in my example there is only 2 different values. Would you be able to give a version that works with a matrix tau, I wonder how much it will slow down. But this is crazy fast, I will probably accept this solution.

Comment: @DylanDijk I have edited the code. It will not slow the code down at all.

Comment: Using a modified `tau` so that not all of the off-diagonal elements are the same with `tau[1,2] = 1` . Then gives different results to the original.

Comment: @DylanDijk is tau not symmetric? Since its 200*200. If you changing tau then change `tau[1,2] = tau[2,1] = 1` and run your code and run my code and compare the results

Comment: Yes, you are right I was being stupid as usual. If I have questions later about the C++ code is it ok if I message you?

Comment: @DylanDijk yes you can message me

Comment: I am now wondering, how you would change the code if you wanted to take the products with lagged rows of the data matrix. For example, if lag = 1 you take the dot product of the first row with the second, and so on.

Comment: @DylanDijk in the code I have, you will have to change the `k` iteration. I am not quite sure though what you mean. Consider asking a NEW question with an example so that we can see what you mean. you can then copy the link to the question here and I will see whether I can help

Comment: Yes, if `k` is selecting the row of the data matrix, then I should change `data[j][k]/2` to `data[j][k+1]/2` if I want a lag of one. I will check, if this works.

Comment: @DylanDijk you will have to change the limits since k+1 will lead to having a row that does not exist in the data. Be careful

Comment: I now have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76101929/rewriting-truncation-of-data-and-covariance-matrix-computation-with-rcpp) and was wondering if you could help?

Comment: @DylanDijk the question is deleted

Comment: I have undeleted it now, I though I had managed to do it.

Comment: @DylanDijk if you managed thats good. been away from the site. too occupied

Comment: I have put [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76101929/rewriting-truncation-of-data-and-covariance-matrix-computation-with-rcpp) up on the question, but it is changing my data object each time I run it, and not sure why. If you could have a look that would be great but no worries if not.

Comment: I fixed this now

Answer (score 8):

Here are some tricks for ~5 times improvement.

***trunc*** **operator**

The slow part here is the `ifelse()` statement which operates on each element separately. We can gain speed by vectorizing it and making it operate on all the passed elements at once:

```
trunc = function(x, tau){
  inds <- abs(x) > tau
  x[inds] <- tau[inds] * sign(x[inds])
  x
}
```

**Outer products**

The slow part here is performing operations row by row. Your case has more rows than columns. The trick - achieve the same result by operating on columns.

```
res  = matrix(0, ncol(data), ncol(data))
tau2 = tau * 2
for(i in 1:ncol(data)) {
  inds = i:ncol(data)
  res[i,inds] = colSums(trunc(data[,inds,drop=FALSE] * data[,i], tau2[rep(i,nrow(data)),inds]))
}
res[lower.tri(res)] = t(res)[lower.tri(res)]
res = res / 2
```

**Short explanation**

Think about how the result is achieved. The final matrix has as many rows and columns as there are columns in the data. For each row you do an outer product and then sum those products.

Now, think about all the operations that went into producing the first element of the result. It takes the first element of the first column, squares it, then the second element of the first column, squares it, etc., applies the truncating operation on all squares and sums them up.

Hence, we can achieve the same result by doing:

```
res <- sum(trunc_operator(data[,1] * data[,1] / 2, tau))
```

Next, think about how the second element is computed in your matrix. It takes the product of first element in the first row and the second element if the first row, adds the first element of the second row multiplied by the second element of the second row, etc., and again applies the truncating operator and sums the result. We can get that by:

```
res <- sum(trunc_operator(data[,1] * data[,2] / 2, tau))
```

But there is one more trick. We can get the first elements for every column at once by multiplying with the whole matrix:

```
res <- colSums(trunc_operator(data[,1] * data / 2, tau))
```

What we see is that we can construct the matrix by iterating over columns rather than over rows. Since you have fewer columns than rows this should be faster.

But there is one more trick. We note that the resulting matrix is always symmetrical. Hence after each iteration we can discard the result for the already computed columns and only store the results for the upper diagonal. Then restore the full matrix at the end.

Benchmark with all 3 proposed solutions:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  original = {
    res = matrix(0, ncol(data), ncol(data))
    for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
      res = res + mat_prod_pairwise_trunc(data[i,], data[i,], tau = tau)
    }
    res
  },
  newProd = {
    tau2 = tau * 2
    res = matrix(0, d, d)
    for (i in seq_len(nrow(dat)))
      res = res + newProd(data[i, ], tau = tau2)
    res = res / 2
    res
  },
  byCol = {
    res  = matrix(0, ncol(data), ncol(data))
    tau2 = tau * 2
    for(i in 1:ncol(data)) {
      inds = i:ncol(data)
      res[i,inds] = colSums(trunc(data[,inds,drop=FALSE] * data[,i], tau2[rep(i,nrow(data)),inds]))
    }
    res[lower.tri(res)] = t(res)[lower.tri(res)]
    res = res / 2
    res
  },
  times = 2,
  unit = "s",
  check = "equal")


Unit: seconds
     expr       min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 original 47.822215 47.822215 49.94679 49.94679 52.07136 52.07136     2  a
  newProd 12.371246 12.371246 12.89065 12.89065 13.41006 13.41006     2   b
    byCol  9.778319  9.778319 10.11568 10.11568 10.45303 10.45303     2   b
```

Comment: Sorry, I should of said that tau is also a `d` by `d` matrix, bad from me.
I give an example below where mine works and yours does not:
`x = matrix(c(1,2,3,4), 2, 2)`
`tau = matrix(c(2,2,1,2), 2, 2)`

Comment: I revamped my whole answer, please take a look and check if it produces the same output as your original solution (just in case)

Comment: When running your code I get the error: `Error in abs(x) > tau : non-conformable arrays`.

Comment: The idea is nice, I think what you mentioned previously about subsetting the i-th row of the tau matrix would then fix it? But, as you are applying `trunc_operator` to a matrix with 19900 rows I think you would also need to change how it is applied, for example using `apply` with `MARGIN=1`.

Comment: maybe you need `x[inds] <- tau[inds] * sign(x[inds])` to make this work

Comment: Yes, something like `rowSums(apply(data[,inds,drop=FALSE] * data[,i] / 2, MARGIN=1, trunc_operator, tau = tau[inds]))`

Comment: @DylanDijk updated, should be working now.

Comment: @DylanDijk final notes - added a benchmark with all 3 solutions so far. Also be ware about `data / sqrt(2)` trick. On my machine the outputs were not equal when compared without this step. Multiplying the tau by 2 and then dividing the final result by 2 seems more computationally stable.

Answer (score 7):

You are evaluating `x %*% t(x)` instead of `tcrossprod(x, NULL)`.  These call BLAS routines `DGEMM` and `DSYRK`, respectively, where only `DSYRK` takes advantage of symmetry.

So your first step should be to call `tcrossprod(x, NULL)` where appropriate and not `x %*% t(x)` or even `tcrossprod(x, x)`.

If the resulting code is still too slow for your purposes, then experiment with different BLAS implementations, depending on your hardware.  But note that external BLAS implementations will not be used if the vector `x` contains special values, namely `NaN`, `NA_real_`, `Inf`, or `-Inf`.

I've retyped your example below, optimizing some of the set-up code and taking some liberties with style and formatting (partly for syntax highlighting in Emacs).  There is a benchmark against your code at the end.

```r
set.seed(0)
n <- 200L
d <- 200L
df <- 4.1

mkDat <- function(x) {
    n <- nrow(x)
    if (n < 2L)
        return(matrix(0, 0L, ncol(x)))
    i1 <- rep.int(1L:(n - 1L), (n - 1L):1L)
    i2 <- sequence.default((n - 1L):1L, 2L:n, 1L)
    x[i1, ] - x[i2, ]
}
dat <- mkDat(matrix(rt(n * d, df), n, d))

mkTau <- function(df, delta, n, d) {
    off <- (df/(df - 2))^2
    on <- 0.5 * (3 * df^2)/(df - 2) * (df - 4) + 1.5 * off
    sqrt(diag(on - off, d, d) + off) *
        sqrt(floor(n / 2)/(2 * log(d) - log(delta)))
}
tau <- mkTau(df, 1/n, n, d)

oldProd <- function(x, y, tau) {
    r <- (x %*% t(y)) / 2
    ifelse(abs(r) > tau, tau * sign(r), r)
}

newProd <- function(x, y = NULL, tau) {
    r <- tcrossprod(x, y)
    if (length(i <- which(abs(r) > tau)))
        r[i] <- tau[i] * sign(r[i])
    r
}

dat.invsqrt2 <- dat / sqrt(2)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    oldLoop = {
        res <- matrix(0, d, d)
        for (i in seq_len(nrow(dat))) 
            res <- res + oldProd(dat[i, ], dat[i, ], tau = tau)
        res
    },
    newLoop = { 
        res <- matrix(0, d, d)
        for (i in seq_len(nrow(dat)))
            res <- res + newProd(dat.invsqrt2[i, ], tau = tau)
        res 
    },
    times = 10L,
    unit = "s",
    check = "equal")
```

```
Unit: seconds
    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 oldLoop 15.422133 15.509987 15.626912 15.564334 15.681810 16.100875    10
 newLoop  3.928236  4.021573  4.040398  4.053979  4.074112  4.087461    10
```