# Rewriting truncation of data and covariance matrix computation with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, performance, rcpp

Given a `tau` vector I want to truncate each row of a data matrix, this is done by the `trunc_operator()` function below. Then compute the sample covariance matrix of the data using this truncated data.

Currently I am using the following functions that are written in R code:

```r
trunc_operator = function(tau, x){
  
  x = ifelse(abs(x) > tau, tau*sign(x), x)
  return(x)
  
}

fun_tau = function(tau, data){t(apply(data, 1, trunc_operator, tau = tau))}


mat_prod = function(x,y){
  x %*% t(y)
}

acf_fun = function(data, lag = 0){
  
  if(lag != 0){
    data_1 = data[-(nrow(data):nrow(data)-lag), ]
    data_2 = data[-(1:lag),]
  } else {
    data_1 = data
    data_2 = data
  }
  
  acf_mat = mapply(mat_prod, asplit(data_1,1), asplit(data_2,1), SIMPLIFY = F)
  acf_mat = 1/length(acf_mat) * Reduce("+", acf_mat)
  return(acf_mat)
}
```

That are then used in this function:

```r
acf_fun_trunc = function(tau, data, lag){
  
  truncated_data = fun_tau(tau = tau, data = data)
  truncated_cov = acf_fun(truncated_data)
  return(truncated_cov)
  
}
```

---

I now want to carry this out using Rcpp, to speed it up as in a previous similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75977129/efficient-way-to-take-a-product-of-vectors-and-then-apply-an-operator-to-the-ou), this sped up the code by a lot. I do not know much about cpp code, and was wondering if someone could provide cpp code that carries out the same thing that my R code does?

---

### Full Reproducible Example to Compare Results:

```r
# Creating Dataset
n = 300
d = 50

data = rt(n = n*50, df = 4.1) / sqrt((4.1/2.1))
data = matrix(data, nrow = n, ncol = d)
tau = 1:50


# Carrying out my R computations

## R functions
trunc_operator = function(tau, x){
  
  x = ifelse(abs(x) > tau, tau*sign(x), x)
  return(x)
  
}

fun_tau = function(tau, data){t(apply(data, 1, trunc_operator, tau = tau))}


mat_prod = function(x,y){
  x %*% t(y)
}

acf_fun = function(data, lag = 0){
  
  if(lag != 0){
    data_1 = data[-(nrow(data):nrow(data)-lag), ]
    data_2 = data[-(1:lag),]
  } else {
    data_1 = data
    data_2 = data
  }
  
  acf_mat = mapply(mat_prod, asplit(data_1,1), asplit(data_2,1), SIMPLIFY = F)
  acf_mat = 1/length(acf_mat) * Reduce("+", acf_mat)
  return(acf_mat)
}


acf_fun_trunc = function(tau, data){
  
  truncated_data = fun_tau(tau = tau, data = data)
  truncated_cov = acf_fun(truncated_data)
  return(truncated_cov)
  
}

# Running job
acf_fun_trunc(tau, data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Before moving to Rcpp, try vectorizing your code. It can be done without `apply`, `mapply`, `asplit`, or `Reduce`:

```
fun_tau2 <- function(tau, data) pmin(pmax(data, -tau), tau)
acf_fun2 <- function(data, lag = 0L) {
  if (lag) {
    tcrossprod(data[,-(nrow(data):(nrow(data) - lag))], data[,-(1:lag)])/ncol(data)
  } else {
    tcrossprod(data)/ncol(data)
  }
}
acf_fun_trunc2 <- function(tau, data, lag = 0L) acf_fun2(fun_tau2(tau, data), lag)

# Running job
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  acf_fun_trunc = acf_fun_trunc(tau, data),
  acf_fun_trunc2 = acf_fun_trunc2(tau, t(data)),
  check = "equal"
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>            expr      min        lq      mean    median         uq       max neval
#>   acf_fun_trunc 8101.801 9283.7015 11591.260 9940.4010 14000.3010 21713.101   100
#>  acf_fun_trunc2  379.502  413.2015   537.038  445.6015   473.0505  9398.901   100
```

Also, I think you want `data_1 = data[-(nrow(data):nrow(data)-lag), ]` to be `data_1 = data[-(nrow(data):(nrow(data)-lag)), ]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have got this so far:

```cpp
Rcpp::cppFunction("
NumericMatrix truncateAndComputeCovariance(NumericMatrix data, NumericVector tau) {
  int n = data.nrow(); // Number of rows in the data matrix
  int p = data.ncol(); // Number of columns in the data matrix
  NumericMatrix covariance(p, p); // Matrix to store the covariance
  
  // Loop through each row of the data matrix
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // Loop through each column of the data matrix
    for (int j = 0; j < p; j++) {
      // Truncate the data element using the corresponding tau value
      if (std::abs(data(i, j)) <= tau[j]) {
        data(i, j) = data(i, j); // No truncation needed
      } else {
        data(i, j) = tau[j] * std::copysign(1.0, data(i, j)); // Truncate to tau with sign
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Compute the covariance without estimating the sample mean
  for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < p; j++) { // Only need to compute the upper triangular part
      double sum = 0.0;
      for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        sum += data(k, i) * data(k, j);
      }
      covariance(i, j) = sum / (n);
      covariance(j, i) = covariance(i, j); // Covariance matrix is symmetric
    }
  }
  
  return covariance;
}")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).